# how to check if the year increments in php for the database reset id

Tags: php, date

hey guys im having a problem about the logic on how to check if the year increments in php. for example to day is 2012 and on the next week will be 2013. is there a easy way to do that in php?.

Comment: Show us what you have tried, please.

Comment: Use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime). Give `+1 week` as argument and get the year using `date`.

Comment: i havent tried anything yet cuz im still confused with the logic. what needs to happen is that when the year change the id number will reset in to 0 again.

Comment: This sounds like it will be fairly easy to do with standard date functions, but you have to be more clear what you want. You mentioned resetting id what id? how many days do you need to add to the date to test if it's next year?

Comment: i dont get it you mean i will increment my year manually? to determine if the year increments?

@pddl0r: the id of the users sir.

Comment: @AlvinJosephValdez I've tried to answer your question but I'm still a little unsure what you are after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function will take the $id and an optional (uses 1 by default) amount of days. If adding the number of days provided goes into the next year $id will be set to 0, if it's the same year it increments the $id by 1.

```
$id = 1;
function idCheck($id, $days = 1) {
    if(date('Y', strtotime('+' . $days . ' days')) > date('Y')) {
        $id = 0;
    } else {
        $id = $id + 1;
    }
    return $id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly Check this code

http://codepad.org/LCpndEBL

```
<?php
    $year = date('Y'); //get current year
    $nextYear = $year + 1;
    echo 'This year: ' . $year. ' Next year:' .$nextYear;
?>
```

Output

```
This year: 2012 Next year:2013
```

Comment: i need a condition like "if (year yesterday > year to day) id = 0 else id+=id"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$year = date('Y'); //get current year
$nextYear = "01 Jan ".($year + 1);
$future = strtotime($nextYear);
$now = time();
$timeleft = $future-$now;
echo $daysleft = round((($timeleft/24)/60)/60);
```

By checking $daysleft count you can found